# limit of a sequence of complex integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to calculate the following limit

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } \oint\limits_{\left| z \right| = 2} {{1 \over {{P_N}^3\left( z \right) - 1}}dz} $$
where ${P_N}\left( z \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^N {{{{z^n}} \over {n!}}} $

Obviously one cannot just simply find the singularities and calculate the integral via the residue theorem, as the singularities are hard to find. so there's some trick here.

The series ${P_N}\left( z \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^N {{{{z^n}} \over {n!}}} $ converges uniformly on our curve to ${e^z}$ so I thought: if I could somehow justify pushing the limit into the integrand then it would be simpler. But even though ${P_N}\left( z \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^N {{{{z^n}} \over {n!}}} $ converges uniformly, I fail to see how ${{1 \over {{P_N}^3\left( z \right) - 1}}}$ converges uniformly.

At this point I ran out of ideas :)

Hints will be welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=\min\{|e^{3z}-1|\,:\,|z|=2\}$. Clearly, $M>0$. Since $({P_N}^3-1)_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to $e^{3z}-1$ in the circle $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,|z|=2\}$, if $N$ is large enough, then$$\bigl|(e^{3z}-1)-({P_N}^3(z)-1)\bigr|<\frac M2.$$ But this implies that $|{P_N}^3(z)-1|>\frac M2$ and therefore$$\left|\frac1{{P_N}^3(z)-1}\right|<\frac2M.$$So, the sequence$$\left(\frac1{{P_N}^3-1}\right)_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$$is uniformly bounded and therefore it converges uniformly to $\frac1{e^{3z}-1}$ in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,|z|=2\}$.